# PHP Check If Function Returns True or False

Tags: php, function

How do I provide the arguments in the second function when checking if the first function returns true or false?

```
public function function1($arg1, $arg2, $arg3){
   if(($arg1 + $arg2 + $arg3) == 15){
      return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
}

public function function2(){
   if($this->function1(what do i put in here???) === true){
      // do something
   }else{
      // do something else
   }
}
```

I only need to know how to provide the arguments when calling the first function. The first function does it job and return true or false. In the second function I just need to know if the return value was true or false. Do I still need to provide the arguments? Why can't I just call the function like $this->function1()?

Would it make more sense to just save the return value in a variable and check that in the second function?

Thank you!

Comment: The function will return `true` or `false` *depending on its arguments*. You are asking how to make a function return `42` without telling us how it works, which is meaningless.

Comment: Umm, it depends on what you've written that function to do?

Comment: Have you already read the [manual page on function arguments](http://php.net/functions.arguments)?

Comment: @Gumbo, That is procedural code...

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible to answer with just the information given.

The correct answer is whatever `function1` expects.  The function takes some information and returns a value based on that.  Without knowing what the function does or how it does it, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Just looking for the correct syntax. $this->$arg1 or something like that. If I just provide the $arg1, $arg2 ... I get undefined variable error.

Comment: @user1002039: Then please edit your question to include a concrete code example.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what arguments the first functions takes... If they are all strings, it could be:

```
public function function1($arg1, $arg2, $arg3){
   ...
   return true;

   ...
   return false;
}

public function function2(){
   if($this->function1("string1", "string1", 55) === true){
      // do something
   }else{
      // do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: The first two are strings and the third one is an integer.

Comment: @user1002039, It would resemble the above code, then.

Comment: I get Undefined variable error for all three arguments.

Comment: @user1002039, Can we see more of the code please? If you have function1 set up the way it is in the question, it will cause an error because the `...` isn't valid.